# How to use php preg_replace to add base tag to head tag

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am outputing some code using a cURL request. In order to change the relative addresses to absolute addresses I want to append a base tag to the head tag.

I was thinking preg_replace can do the trick but i am not too sure about the regex.

i want to append this tag

```
<base href="url">
```

What can be the possible regex to append this tag to the $output i get my cURL request.

Here is the code for the cURL request I am using.

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set a single option...
// ... or an array of options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // Set a referer

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
 $output = str_replace('</head>','<base href="'.$href.'"></head>',$output);
//$output= preg_replace("/<head>/", "<head><base href=".$href.">", $output); 

 echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: $yourString = str_replace('</head>', '<base href="url"></head>', $yourString);

Comment: @MohammadAlabed you should make this an answer as it's more sensible than using an actual regular expression to solve this trivial problem

Answer (score 1):

**First**, be sure that your code return a string of the HTML ([curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php))

**Second**, you do not need preg_replace,,, try this:

```
$yourString = str_replace('</head>', '<base href="url"></head>', $yourString);
```

Comment: I was already trying this but it isnt working Here is the code i used  $output = str_replace('<head>','<head><base href="'.$href.'">',$output);

Comment: no ..  your code replace the opening tag .. you should replace the closing tag </head>

Comment: Even after that it doesnot work I get the $output in my case from a cURL request. could that be a problem

Comment: could you add your code to the question, so that we can figure it out

Comment: you must read about curl_exec it returns Boolean, you have to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = 1